# Что такое cli утилита использующая модуль python

Tags: python, linux, bash

При устройстве на работу я получил тестовое задание: Нужно сделать модуль python и cli утилиту linux (использующую этот
модуль на python). Я написал скрипт на Python и bash скрипт, который подготавливает файлы для работы python скрипта и запускает его. Роботадатель сообщил что моя программа не является cli утилитой и отказал. Что такое cli утилита и чем она отличается от того что я сделал?

Comment: А какие-то аргументы командной строки эта ваша связка понимала, предусматривала? Или все параметры были жёстко прошиты в `bash` скрипте? "The command line interface (also known as CLI) is a means to interact with a command line script."

Comment: Все параметры были прошиты в bash скрипте, так как он должен был сравнивать список пакетов с двух конкретных веток по запросу и создавать конкретный результирующий файл

Comment: Ну по-хорошему надо их, конечно, спрашивать, но, видимо, они хотели, чтобы всё же можно было указать эти параметры через командную строку. Сегодня ветки одни, а завтра другие и т.д. Все такие параметры должны приниматься из командной строки. И на питоне это не сложно сделать, библиотека `argparse` в него прямо встроена.

Comment: @CrazyElf Вы считаете что утилита отличается от скрипта тем что она может принимать параметры из консоли? Что ж, если это действительно так спасибо! Немогу поверить что из-за такой глупости я завалил собес(((( а параметры можно и из bash скрипта принимать... так как именно его вызывают из консоли